# ASP.NET Core routing based on query parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I'm migrating old (bad) code for ASP.NET Web API (.NET Framework 4.5) to ASP.NET Core 6. I must maintain backward compatibility.

There are two methods on controller that are different only by arguments:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get([FromUri] string tags, [FromUri] string counter) {...}
public IEnumerable<string> Get([FromUri] string folders, [FromUri] string tags, [FromUri] string counter) {...}
```

The routing is typical (nothing special):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("default",
  "api/{controller}/{id}",
  new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
  null,
  null });
```

This works in .NET Framework 4.5, the following requests are routed correctly:

```
/api/RTData2?tags=0,1,2&counter=762
/api/RTData2?folders=0,1,2&tags=11,12,17&counter=133
```

How do I make that work with ASP.NET Core? (the client/web side is out of my touch).

Thank you in advance.

The only relevant information I was able to find: [Query parameter routing with asp .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022983/query-parameter-routing-with-asp-net-core)

But that is not really my case.

Comment: And what is the problem? What error do you have? I don't think that there is a big difference between net and net.core routing

Comment: It throws AmbiguousMatchException.

Comment: AmbiguousMatchException can be thrown on the server side since  you have 2 very similar actions, Why do you need 2  actions with the same name? Do you know that parameters order doesn't matter?

Comment: That is old legacy code. I cannot change client side. URLs must remain the same.

Comment: Somehow older ASP.NET (.NET Framework) does the routing based on query arguments only.

Comment: I updated my answer according to your explanations

Answer (score 0):

you have to actions with the same name "get", maybe you need to add action name to separate them, something like this

```
[NonAction]
private IEnumerable<string> Get(string tags, string counter) {...}

[HttpGet("~/api/RTData2")] 
public IEnumerable<string> Get(string tags,  string counter, string folders  ) {

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(folders)) return Get(tags,counter);
...your usual code

}
```

routing doesn't check how many query string parameters you url has. It will call the action without any parameters as well.

Comment: That is what I'm using, combining two (or more) Web API methods into one with combination of nullable arguments. Then invoke appropriate code based on nullables. Thank you all for sharing ideas.